# ADX STUDIO - Set the default Homepage for specific portal user

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, adxstudio-portals

I have two kind of user in my portal, a customer user and an agent user.
I want to change the default Homepage of Agent user every time he/she logs in or clicks to a Homepage button to the website instead of the customer's default homepage.ie (Agent Homepage)
Currently, I was able to achieve this through below code:

```
var userId = AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

var portal = PortalCrmConfigurationManager.CreatePortalContext();
var usercontext = portal.User;
var context = portal.ServiceContext;
var contact = (from c in context.CreateQuery("contact")
               where c["contactid"].Equals(userId)
               select c).First();
var isAgentUser = contact.GetAttributeValue<bool>("bh_isagentuser");

if (isAgentUser == true)
{
    return Redirect("/agent-home");
}
else
{
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

I want to know if there's another workaround for ADX studio to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than redirecting to a different web page, you could change what information is displayed on the home page based on the detected user type. A simple example using Liquid would be to include a different web template depending on the user type:

```cs
{% if user.bh_isAgentUser %}
  {% include "Agent Home" %}
{% else %}
  {% include "Default Home" %}
{% endif %}
```

You would add the different home page rendering logic inside each of the `Agent Home` and `Default Home` web templates.

The above Liquid could be inserted into the copy field of the home page, or the home page could be changed to use a web template with this Liquid inside it. This choice would depend on the structural elements of the rendered web page that need to change.

See documentation on the [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/liquid-objects#user) object, [include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/template-tags#include) tag, and [web templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/store-content-web-templates) for more details.